# Xdt Transform To Add Security Mode to multiple bindings

Tags: asp.net, xdt-transform, xdt

My web application makes use of multiple web services, so I have bindings to each of them, like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICityDataService" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000" />
      </binding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBuildingDataService" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000" />
      </binding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEventDataService" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000" />
      </binding>
      ...
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

On my development environment, I cannot use SSL (and do not need it), but when I go to deploy, I have to use SSL, so I need to add a security mode to each of those bindings.  I applied the following XDT transform:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding>
        <security mode="Transport" xdt:Transform="Insert">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

But that only adds the security mode to the first binding.  But even after reading the [XDT Transform documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) and a number of articles and SO question/answers, I cannot figure out how to specify a locator that will select all the bindings so that child node gets added to all of them.  I could specify each of the bindings by name, but that seems clunky.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, what you want to achieve (i.e. inserting new element on multiple elements) is not supported by XDT transformations, which is a pity!

One way to workaround the problem might be to add the security node to all your bindings for your development environment and set it to **None**.

You can then have some global replacements to update all attributes to **Transport**

Your web.config should be something like

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICityDataService" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBuildingDataService" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEventDataService" allowCookies="true" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" maxBufferSize="10000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10000000" maxArrayLength="10000000" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And your XDT transform should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <!-- Define Global Replacements -->
  <replaceAll>
      <WCF_replaceBindingSecurityMode xdt:Locator="XPath(//basicHttpBinding/binding/security)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(mode)" mode="Transport" />
  </replaceAll>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I suspected that XDT did not have what I wanted, and you are right, it is a pity.  I had actually added transforms that located each binding and inserted the security mode node after the readerQuotas node.  But, your solution is more elegant and less code.  Thanks a ton.